# Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel updates

Tags: 16.04, aws

How are kernel updates applied for Ubuntu 16.04 AWS Image?

If we are running v4.4, do we need to apply security updates for 4.4, OR our system is still vulnerable as the latest available kernel version is 4.15.

To summarize, do kernel packages gets updated to the latest train version (v4.4.0-1094.105) or to the latest train(v4.15) for Ubuntu 16.04.